# With Slate, how to include additional markdown at the start of the document?

Tags: openapi-generator, widdershins

I'm using [Widdershins](https://github.com/Mermade/widdershins) to generate a markdown file from my OpenAPI spec, and then using [Slate](https://github.com/slatedocs/slate/) to transform it into a static docs site.

I'd like to add an introduction at the start of the HTML. However, using the `includes` option adds markdown to the end of the HTML, rather than the start.

Is there some way to get `includes` to put files at the start instead of the end?